# $(\textbf A \cdot \textbf A ^ T) ^ {-1}$ resulting in singular matrix ? How to overcome this?

Tags: matrices

A is Non Square matrix, where '$m$' rows < '$n$' columns.

For example $m=10$; $n=15$;

When calculating $(\textbf A \cdot\textbf A ^ T) ^ {-1}$ results a singular matrix and inverse fails.

So how to overcome this? So that, I can multiply $\textbf A^T$ with above equation?

I am not so familiar with matrices. I heard that we can do this with eigen values/ vectors. Please do the needful

Comment: I'm sorry, but "please do the needful" is actually kind of funny.  If I'm thinking right, you should only get a singular matrix if the row vectors in $\textbf A$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: By definition $(AA^T)^{-1}$ exists if and only if $AA^T$ is non singular and in this case it is non singular as well.

Comment: If your matrix is singular then there's is nothing you can do to change that. The best you can do in this case is probably to compute the [pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got Inverse by Singular Value Decomposition & Principal Component Analysis concept by Jonathan Harel http://www.klab.caltech.edu/~harel/

Suppose we have an **m x n** matrix **A**, in which we interpret the COLUMNS to be sample vectors. For any of the **m** components of each sample vector, we can define the sample variance (we assume zero-mean data), and we wish to find direction in **$R{^m}$** which have maximal variance over the set. The idea is that a few such directions span a subspace of **$R{^m}$** which captures most of the variance in the data. We can then project a new vector onto this subspace as means of reducing dimensionality.

If the rows of **A** sum to zero, then the covarience matrix is an **m x m** matrix **C** such that:

**C** = **E[**${a_i}$${a_j}$***]* 
            = const. $AA{^T}$

where $a{_i}$ and $a{_j}$ are the $i{^{th}}$ and $j{^{th}}$ components (i,j $w\in \{1,2,.., m\}$) from the same randomly selected sample vector, and const = 1/n .We will drop this leading constant from here on as it does not play a role in the analysis. The variance of the data in  **A** projected onto an arbitary direction v turns out to be :

var(v) = $v^T$Cv = $\sum_{i,j}$$v_i$$v_j$$C_{ij}$. (1)

Since variance must be positive, then $v^TCv>0$ for all real nonzero v, and because C is also symmetric, **C** must be positive semi-definite.

According to optimization theory, the variance quantity (1) is maximized(subject to $v^Tv=1$) When

grad($v^TCv$) = $\lambda$.grad($v^Tv$)[grad wrt components of v]

=> **Cv** = $\lambda v$

Therefore, the direction with maximum variance is an eigenvector of **C**. We note that the variance of an eigenvector is

$e^TCe=e^T\lambda e = \lambda$

So the line along the principal eigenvector of **C** is the one-dimentional subspace in which the data (projected onto such a subspace) in **A** have the gretest variance. The direction orthogonal to that eigenvector with largest variance among all possible orthogonal directions is given by the second eigenvector, etc.. The eigenvectors are orthogonal because C is symmetric.

Thus, if

**C**=$U \wedge U^T$ 
is the eigendecomposition of C, then

**A**=$U \sqrt{\wedge V^T}$ is the singular value decomposition of A.

Coded in R(http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/pages/svd_demos.htm):

library(MASS)

A <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 9, 4)## 9 rows n 4 columns

A.svd <- svd(A)

A.svd$\$d$ ##The non-zero singular values of A

**Result of A.svd$\$d$ :-**

```
## [1] 3.46e+00 1.73e+00 1.73e+00 1.92e-16
```

**ds <- diag(1/A.svd$\$d$[1:3])** ## variance along the principal component

**u <- A.u** ##left-singular vectors of a A

**v <- A.v** ##left-singular vectors of a A

**us <- as.matrix(u[, 1:3])** ## Convert to matrix format

**vs <- as.matrix(v[, 1:3])** ## Convert to matrix format

**(A.ginv <- vs %*% ds %*% t(us))** ## Inverse Step

```
##         [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]
## [1,]  0.0833  0.0833  0.0833  0.0833  0.0833  0.0833  0.0833  0.0833
## [2,]  0.2500  0.2500  0.2500 -0.0833 -0.0833 -0.0833 -0.0833 -0.0833
## [3,] -0.0833 -0.0833 -0.0833  0.2500  0.2500  0.2500 -0.0833 -0.0833
## [4,] -0.0833 -0.0833 -0.0833 -0.0833 -0.0833 -0.0833  0.2500  0.2500
##         [,9]
## [1,]  0.0833
## [2,] -0.0833
## [3,] -0.0833
## [4,]  0.2500
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).